# Set 500 subtypes in ArcGIS 10.0 Desktop from a csv list

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

Does anyone know of a way I could import a long list of Subtypes from a csv list and if there is a maximum number of subtypes that one can import? My list consists of biotops and contains 500 entries. For data entry purposes in ArcGIS, it would be advantageous to have these a subtypes. But in reality maybe 500 is too many for ArcGIS. Has anyone had a similar case?

Comment: Doy mean a domain or a subtype?  Will other fields depend or change according to these values?

Comment: no other fields with change. I just need the drop down list for easy editing.

Comment: @Then you need a domain. If you convert from CSV to a dbf/table, you can use this tool: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000001v000000

Comment: Can you edit your Question to make it clear whether you mean subtypes or a domain (which seems more likely), and also include a graphic with some sample rows from your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with a simple model. Firstly you need to set the field that will be the sub type field, this will be a numeric field. I created a field called ID of type long. I did this in ArcCatalog.

Your CSV file should be in the format of:

```
id,"type"
0,"type 0"
1,"type 1"
2,"type 2"
```

Then create the model as shown below:

[image: Model for adding sub-types]

Comment: fantastic....Ill try it out.